# Past Continuous for background info

Tags: past-continuous

Let's suppose my friend missed a lecture by our professor Mr. Johnson today and he (my friend) wants to  find out how it was.

- How was the lecture?
- Not much, Mr Johnson was telling jokes, so we learned nothing.

As far as I understand, Past Continuous ("was telling") is preferable here because it provides context or background info for main events ("we learned nothing).

Which would be more natural here: was telling jokes or told jokes? Or they are both equally natural in this context?

Comment: The continuous tense suggests that a large part of the lecture consisted of jokes, which corresponds with students claiming to have 'learned nothing'. If he had just told a few jokes, it might have helped them to remember the serious points he was making!

Comment: Thank you! would it be it natural to answer with Simple Past here? - "He told jokes, so we learned nothing"?

Comment: Aside: "Not much" is not a reasonable response to "How was the lecture?". The question asks for an assessment, but "not much" is a quantity.

Comment: No - I meant to imply that "He told jokes" (unless you specified "all the time" or similar) would probably be understood to mean just that he told _some_ jokes to liven up his lecture.

Answer (score 1):

Continuous is correct.

"*He **told** jokes, so we learned nothing*" suggests that we learned nothing at all during the entire lecture because he told jokes --perhaps very few-- at some point, not necessarily throughout the lecture. Continuous suggests that the professor was mostly telling jokes.